# Using timer in .Net Core for some scheduled task?

Tags: .net, timer, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I have created a timer in startup.cs file like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
//here i am reading value from appsettings.json
var timeForScheTask = Configuration.GetSection("TimeForScheduledTask");
var time = timeForScheTask.GetValue<string>("TimeToRun"); //it returns 09:00:00 PM

        AutoResetEvent autoEvent = null;
        autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        tm = new Timer(Execute, autoEvent, 10000, 10000);
}
```

Below is the Execute method of timer:

```
public void Execute(System.Object stateInfo)
    {
        if (_counter < 10)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Call #" + _counter);
            _counter++;
            return;
        }

        //Console.WriteLine("Final call");
        tm.Dispose();
    }
```

I just want to run some script/query everyday at 12:00:00 night, I just want to know what to right in this line of code,

```
        tm = new Timer(Execute, autoEvent, 1000, 1000);
```

instead of 1000,1000

Generally I don't use .net/ timer to run any scheduled task,  but this time i am just experimenting with this and that too .net core, in which microsoft has changed the timer thing a bit.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Timers are meant for short durations, not scheduling daily tasks. What happens if your application terminates for example?

Comment: Besides - what is the question? Did you actually encounter a problem? What do you mean "Microsoft has changed the timer"? The signature is the same as it always was. It *never* worked with a specific time. It always worked with intervals

Comment: with "Microsoft has changed the timer" I mean- https://adrientorris.github.io/aspnet-core/how-to-implement-timer-netcoreapp1-0-netcoreapp1-1.html

Comment: timer always works with intervals...but is there any way i can use it to run at a particular time?

Comment: No, Microsoft hasn't changed anything. The System.Threading.Timer was always available and used. That particular author just found out about it now

Comment: As for specific times, I repeat, the timer is *NOT* meant to schedule daily tasks. The documentation already shows how to run at a specific time - just calculate the timespan between the current and target time and pass it as the `dueTime` parameter, eg `DateTime.Today.AddHours(17) - DateTime.Now` will return the interval between now and 17:00

Comment: If you want to implement scheduled tasks for a web site, use a library like HangFire. Application pools can get recycled, threads can be aborted. Timers can result in multiple executions on a web farm. Hangfire takes care of all these, and adds monitoring to your tasks

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for the explaination :)

Answer (score 1):

The third and fourth parameters for a Timer constructor are due Time and period respectively.

Due time is the time left before your callback **execute** method run. So Instead of using this constructor use the constructor with four parameters use the constructor with single parameter i.e., only callback.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms149618(v=vs.110).aspx

Then create a method which takes a parameter of current DateTime (DateTime.Now) and calculates the interval between datetime.now and your requirement 12:00:00 night.Now set the due time with the difference obtained in this method using change property of the timer.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz1c7148(v=vs.110).aspx

The other parameter is periodic signalling if you want it to be periodic set the interval to your period. I think in your case its one day. So it would be 24*60*60*1000. If you want to disable it set **Timeout.Infinite**.